# \Windows\ versus \Windows\System32 - File location conventions

Tags: windows, directory, conventions, system32

Is there a standard convention for the types of files that go in \Windows\ versus those that go in \Windows\System32 ??

I'm working on an SDK that has a variety of DLLs a helper exe, and a Windows service exe.  The previous guy who worked on the code put the two exe files in \Windows\ and the DLLs in \Windows\System32\  But it seems to me that they should likely all go in \Windows\System32\

Which would you do?

**Edit:** <del>I am NOT trying to debate the merits of if they should go there at all.  Plenty of apps install things to System32...especially for services or drivers (both of which I'm dealing with).  Granted, I'm not saying it's right...as I said, I didn't create this initially...for the sake of this question.  If those were your only choices...what goes where?</del>

**Edit:** OK, point taken. I didn't really think I was going to be able to convince the "architect" of this project to move them out of either of those two directories... but at this point I'll try harder.  Agreed...nothing should be put in those folders.

Comment: But they are not your only choices.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

They shouldn't go in either! Your application files go in your application directory, not in the Windows directories under any circumstances - those are for the ioperating system to use, not you.

And it doesn't matter whether your application is installing executables,  DLLs, drivers, fonts, configuration files, whatever. They do not go in the Windows directories. The fact that a few badly designed and badly written applications do install things there is no execuse.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree.  Windows\ and Windows\System32 should be considered sacrosanct and completely and uterly left alone.  the service and ALL supporting code belong in it's own directory under \Program Files\<company name>\<product>

Comment: As a a side note, I look forward to the day that MS finally wakes up and locks those directories down to access by third parties.

Answer (score 3):

I would put the files under Program Files where they belong.  Windows and Windows\System32 are for the operating system's use only.